# All errors not added to PageMessages

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I am throwing some custom exceptions in my controller and I'm noticing when there are multiple errors, the errors do not display all at once.  Rather they display one at a time on the page.  I'm using the `pageMessages` component.

I think the issue is in the controller on how I'm adding the errors in the catch block for all the different  methods.

Here is my class:

```
public with sharing class CallReportControllerExtension {

private Call_Report__c callReport;

public Boolean isEditMode {get; set;}
public List<Participants> participantLinesForPage {get; set;}
public List<ProductsPresented> productLinesForPage {get; set;}
public List<Tasks> taskLinesForPage {get; set;}

public CallReportControllerExtension(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
    this.callReport = (Call_Report__c)stdController.getRecord();
    isEditMode = isEditPage(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('save_new'));
    refreshParticipantLineItems();  
    refreshProductLineItems();
    refreshTaskLineItems();
}

public PageReference save() {
    Savepoint sp = Database.setSavepoint();
    try {
        insert callReport;
        upsertParticipants(callReport.Id);
        upsertProducts(callReport.Id);
        upsertTasks(callReport.Id);
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        ApexPages.addMessages(ex);
        Database.rollback(sp); 
        callReport = callReport.clone(false);
        return null;        
    }
    PageReference pageRef = new ApexPages.StandardController(callReport).view();
    pageRef.setRedirect(true);
    return pageRef;
}

public PageReference updateCallReport() {
    Savepoint sp = Database.setSavepoint();
    try {
        update callReport;
        upsertParticipants(callReport.Id);
        upsertProducts(callReport.Id);
        upsertTasks(callReport.Id);
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        ApexPages.addMessages(ex);
        Database.rollback(sp); 
        return null;            
    }
    PageReference pageRef = new ApexPages.StandardController(callReport).view();
    pageRef.setRedirect(true);
    return pageRef;         
}

private PageReference upsertParticipants(String callreportid) {
    List<Participant__c> recordsToUpsert = new List<Participant__c>();
    for(Participants parts : participantLinesForPage) {
        if(parts.participantLine.Call_Report__c == null) {
            Participant__c p = new Participant__c();
            p.Call_Report__c = callreportid;
            if(!String.isEmpty(parts.accountId)) {
                p.Account__c = parts.accountId;
            } else {
                p.Account__c = null;
            }
            if(!String.isEmpty(parts.contactId)) {
                p.Contact__c = parts.contactId;
            } else {
                p.Contact__c = null;
            } 
            if(!String.isEmpty(parts.userId)) {
                p.User__c = parts.userId;
            } else {
                p.User__c = null;
            }
            recordsToUpsert.add(p);
        }
        else {
            if(!String.isEmpty(parts.accountId)) {
                parts.participantLine.Account__c = parts.accountId;
            } else {
                parts.participantLine.Account__c = null;
            }
            if(!String.isEmpty(parts.contactId)) {
                parts.participantLine.Contact__c = parts.contactId;
            } else {
                parts.participantLine.Contact__c = null;
            }
            if(!String.isEmpty(parts.userId)) {
                parts.participantLine.User__c = parts.userId;
            } else {
                parts.participantLine.User__c = null;
            }
            recordsToUpsert.add(parts.participantLine);
        }
    }
    if(!recordsToUpsert.isEmpty() && recordsToUpsert.size() > 0) {
        try {
            upsert recordsToUpsert;
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            ApexPages.addMessages(ex);
            return null;
        }
    }
    return null;        
}  

private PageReference upsertProducts(String callreportid) {
    List<Products_Presented__c> recordsToUpsert = new List<Products_Presented__c>();
    for(ProductsPresented prodPresented : productLinesForPage) {
        if(prodPresented.productLine.Call_Report__c == null) {
            Products_Presented__c pp = new Products_Presented__c();
            pp.Call_Report__c = callreportid;
            if(!String.isEmpty(prodPresented.productId)) {
                pp.Product__c = prodPresented.productId;
            } else {
                throw new CallReportException('The Product presented field is blank. Please select a product.');
            }
            pp.Notes__c = prodPresented.productLine.Notes__c;
            pp.At_Risk__c = prodPresented.productLine.At_Risk__c;
            recordsToUpsert.add(pp);
        }
        else {
            if(!String.isEmpty(prodPresented.productId)) {
                prodPresented.productLine.Product__c = prodPresented.productId;
            } else {
                throw new CallReportException('The Product presented field is blank. Please select a product.');
            }
            prodPresented.productLine.Notes__c = prodPresented.productLine.Notes__c;
            prodPresented.productLine.At_Risk__c = prodPresented.productLine.At_Risk__c;
            recordsToUpsert.add(prodPresented.productLine);
        }
    }
    if(!recordsToUpsert.isEmpty() && recordsToUpsert.size() > 0) {
        try {
            upsert recordsToUpsert;
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            ApexPages.addMessages(ex);
            return null;
        }
    }
    return null;        
}   

private PageReference upsertTasks(String callreportid) {
    List<Task> recordsToUpsert = new List<Task>();
    for(Tasks t : taskLinesForPage) {
        if(t.taskLine.WhatId == null) {
            Task task = new Task();
            task.WhatId = callreportid;
            if(!String.isEmpty(t.whoId)) {
                task.WhoId = t.whoId;
            } else {
                task.WhoId = null;
            }
            if(String.isEmpty(t.userId)) throw new CallReportException('The Assigned To field is blank. Please select a user that is assigned this task.');
            task.OwnerId = t.userId;
            task.Subject = 'Call Report Task';
            task.ActivityDate = t.taskLine.ActivityDate;
            task.Description = t.taskLine.Description;
            task.Status = 'Not Started';
            task.Priority = 'Normal';
            recordsToUpsert.add(task);
        }
        else {
            if(!String.isEmpty(t.whoId)) {
                t.taskLine.WhoId = t.whoId;
            } else {
                t.taskLine.WhoId = null;
            }
            if(String.isEmpty(t.userId)) throw new CallReportException('The Assigned To field is blank. Please select a user that is assigned this task.');
            t.taskLine.OwnerId = t.userId;
            t.taskLine.ActivityDate = t.taskLine.ActivityDate;
            t.taskLine.Description = t.taskLine.Description;
            recordsToUpsert.add(t.taskLine);
        }
    }
    if(!recordsToUpsert.isEmpty() && recordsToUpsert.size() > 0) {
        try {
            upsert recordsToUpsert;
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            ApexPages.addMessages(ex);
            return null;
        }
    }
    return null;        
}

public PageReference addParticipant() {
    Participant__c newRecord = new Participant__c();
    participantLinesForPage.add(new Participants(participantLinesForPage.size(), newRecord, newRecord.Account__r.Id, newRecord.Account__r.Name, newRecord.Contact__r.Id, newRecord.Contact__r.Name, newRecord.User__r.Id, newRecord.User__r.Name));
    return null;
}

public PageReference deleteParticipant() {
    Integer selectId = Integer.valueOf(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('del'));
    Participants toRemove = participantLinesForPage.get(selectId);
    try {
        if(toRemove.participantLine.Id != null) {
            delete [select Id from Participant__c where Id =: toRemove.ParticipantLine.Id]; 
        }
        participantLinesForPage.remove(selectId);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ApexPages.addMessages(e);
    }  
    Integer iterate = 0;
    for(Participants parts : participantLinesForPage) {
        parts.iterate = iterate;
        iterate +=1;
    }    
    return null;
}

public PageReference addProduct() {
    Products_Presented__c newRecord = new Products_Presented__c();
    productLinesForPage.add(new ProductsPresented(productLinesForPage.size(), newRecord, newRecord.Product__r.Id, newRecord.Product__r.Name));
    return null;
}

public PageReference deleteProduct() {
    Integer selectId = Integer.valueOf(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('del'));
    ProductsPresented toRemove = productLinesForPage.get(selectId);
    try {
        if(toRemove.productLine.Id != null) {
            delete [select Id from Products_Presented__c where Id =: toRemove.productLine.Id]; 
        }
        productLinesForPage.remove(selectId);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ApexPages.addMessages(e);
    }  
    Integer iterate = 0;
    for(ProductsPresented prods : productLinesForPage) {
        prods.iterate = iterate;
        iterate +=1;
    }    
    return null;
}

public PageReference addTask() {
    Task newRecord = new Task();
    taskLinesForPage.add(new Tasks(taskLinesForPage.size(), newRecord, newRecord.Who.Id, newRecord.Who.Name, newRecord.Owner.Id, newRecord.Owner.Name));
    return null;
}

public PageReference deleteTask() {
    Integer selectId = Integer.valueOf(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('del'));
    Tasks toRemove = taskLinesForPage.get(selectId);
    try {
        if(toRemove.taskLine.Id != null) {
            delete [select Id from Task where Id =: toRemove.taskLine.Id]; 
        }
        taskLinesForPage.remove(selectId);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ApexPages.addMessages(e);
    }  
    Integer iterate = 0;
    for(Tasks tasks : taskLinesForPage) {
        tasks.iterate = iterate;
        iterate +=1;
    }    
    return null;
}

private void refreshParticipantLineItems() {
    List<Participant__c> lineItems = [select Account__c, Account__r.Id, Account__r.Name, Contact__c, Contact__r.Id, Contact__r.Name, User__c, User__r.Id, User__r.Name, Spent_Amount__c, Call_Report__c from Participant__c where Call_Report__c =: callReport.Id];

    participantLinesForPage = new List<Participants>();

    Integer iterate = 0;
    for(Participant__c p : lineItems) {
        participantLinesForPage.add(new Participants(iterate, p, String.valueOf(p.Account__r.Id), p.Account__r.Name, String.valueOf(p.Contact__r.Id), p.Contact__r.Name, String.valueOf(p.User__r.Id), p.User__r.Name));
        iterate += 1;
    }
}

private void refreshProductLineItems() {
    List<Products_Presented__c> prodsPresentedLineItems = [select Product__r.Id, Product__r.Name, Call_Report__c, Notes__c, At_Risk__c from Products_Presented__c where Call_Report__c =: callReport.Id];

    productLinesForPage = new List<ProductsPresented>();

    Integer iterate = 0;
    for(Products_Presented__c pp : prodsPresentedLineItems) {
        productLinesForPage.add(new ProductsPresented(iterate, pp, String.valueOf(pp.Product__r.Id), pp.Product__r.Name));
        iterate += 1;
    }
}

private void refreshTaskLineItems() {
    List<Task> taskLineItems = new List<Task>();
    if(callReport.Id != null) {
        taskLineItems = [select Who.Id, Who.Name, ActivityDate, Description, WhatId, OwnerId, Owner.Id, Owner.Name from Task where WhatId =: callReport.Id];
    }

    taskLinesForPage = new List<Tasks>();

    Integer iterate = 0;
    for(Task t : taskLineItems) {
        taskLinesForPage.add(new Tasks(iterate, t, String.valueOf(t.Who.Id), t.Who.Name, String.valueOf(t.Owner.Id), t.Owner.Name));
        iterate += 1;
    }
}

private Boolean isEditPage(String param) {
    Boolean retval = true;
    if(param != null) {
        retval = false;
    }
    return retval;
}

class Participants {    
    public Integer iterate {get; set;}
    public Participant__c participantLine {get; set;}
    public String accountId {get; set;}
    public String accountName {get; set;}
    public String contactId {get; set;}
    public String contactName {get; set;}
    public String userId {get; set;}
    public String userName {get; set;}  

    public Participants(Integer iterate, Participant__c participantLine, String accountId, String accountName, String contactId, String contactName, String userId, String userName) {
        this.iterate = iterate;
        this.participantLine = participantLine;
        this.accountId = accountId;
        this.accountName = accountName;
        this.contactId = contactId;
        this.contactName = contactName;
        this.userId = userId;
        this.userName = userName;
    }
}

class ProductsPresented {
    public Integer iterate {get; set;}
    public Products_Presented__c productLine {get; set;}
    public String productId {get; set;}
    public String productName {get; set;}

    public ProductsPresented(Integer iterate, Products_Presented__c productLine, String productId, String productName) {
        this.iterate = iterate;
        this.productLine = productLine;
        this.productId = productId;
        this.productName = productName;
    }
}

class Tasks {
    public Integer iterate {get; set;}
    public Task taskLine {get; set;}
    public String whoId {get; set;}
    public String whoName {get; set;}
    public String userId {get; set;}
    public String userName {get; set;}

    public Tasks(Integer iterate, Task taskLine, String whoId, String whoName, String userId, String userName) {
        this.iterate = iterate;
        this.taskLine = taskLine;
        this.whoId = whoId;
        this.whoName = whoName;
        this.userId = userId;
        this.userName = userName;
    }
}
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example you have four DML operations and the first operation falls, so the code does not continue to the second operation. So you only displays the first error on the page.

```
try {
       action 1;
       action 2;
       action 3;
       action 4;
} catch(Exception ex) {
    ApexPages.addMessages(ex);
}
```

If it necessary you can change it to something like this.

```
try { action 1;}catch(exception ex){ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,ex.getMessage()));}
try { action 2;}catch(exception ex){ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,ex.getMessage()));}...
if(ApexPages.hasMessages())return null;
```